# Fast evaluation of a decision forest

Tags: optimization, decision-tree, avx

I have some decision trees (1000-3000) which need to be evaluated as fast as possible. They all access the same set of double values. There are no categorical values at all (so all values are just numerical).

What is the fastest way to do this? At the moment I generate some C-code at runtime and compile it with the heaviest optimizations for the local architecture. The generated code looks like this (similar, but much larger):

```
static inline double eval_tree0() {
   if (*(const double *)0x12345 < 1.2345) {
     if (*(const double *)0x4563456 < 2.2243) {
        return 1.2111;
     }
     else {
        return 5.2111;
     }
   }
   else {
      return 1.234;
   }
}

double eval() {
  return eval_tree0() + eval_tree1() + ...;
}
```

Is there something more performant? I was thinking about using AVX to evaluate multiple trees at once, but this seems to be tricky and I'm not sure if the performance is that much better.

Has anyone an idea what's the very fastest possibility to evaluate a bunch of decision trees for a given input (batch size is 1)? Maybe even something with AVX?

Thanks

Comment: There might be some possibilities for AVX, but if they're based around VGATHERQPD (which it pretty much has to be if the trick is to walk multiple trees at the same time, unless the trees were somehow packed in a weird way?) that's not really great. Maybe something else can be done, such as doing multiple levels at the same time (doing some redundant work, but cheaply) and then somehow resolving the actual path, idk. Can you show some code, that might help for inspiration

Comment: Doing 3 levels at once, getting the comparison results with VMOVMSKPS and using a small array to turn that into an index doesn't sound bad, I haven't worked this out though

Comment: I'm not familiar with decision trees in this sense, only the flow-chart sense, so I'm not sure what actual algorithmic operations you're going to need, or how the input might be stored.  If you could shed some light on that, I might have an idea how AVX could be applies.  (How many doubles are in your set?  And would it be useful to give an example of what the C looks like for one or two of the trees?)  Or if there's some useful overview of this kind of problem, you could link to it, and I might or might not go learn about it :P

Comment: Loading a `double` from an arbitrary hard-coded absolute address like `0x12345` seems weird.  (And I assume your real `double` address are 8-byte aligned, not that it matters for AVX).  But anyway, if all the trees have the same structure, you could broadcast those two doubles into vectors, and load vectors to compare against.  Then perhaps 2x `vblendvpd`.  The compare vectors, and the blend sources, would need the values for 4 different decision trees interleaved.  Note that you could get twice as much work done per instruction if you were using `float`.

Comment: Are you seriously generating code with hard-coded addresses? Can't you store your trees in a way that you can traverse them without generating/compiling C code at run-time?

Comment: Consider using JITs (see the one of LLVM and GCC that prodide high-performance) rather than generating C code at runtime. Some JITs can do runtime optimizations that can hardly be done by static compilers. Branchless optimizations may help more than vectorization especially since vectorzation is probably hard to use here. It is often better if conditionals are hard to predict by the processor.

Comment: @chtz: The code must be fast and traversing a tree data structure was way too slow (it was done before).

Comment: @PeterCordes: That is a good idea. Rapidscorer makes something a bit similar, but with some tricks: https://ai.stanford.edu/~wzou/kdd_rapidscorer.pdf I'll probably go for that.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: The branches are relatively unpredictable, so I think a JIT cannot create something way better than the C-code. If I have time, I'll give it a try. Thanks:)!

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, all double-addresses are aligned in the real code.

Comment: Jérôme's point is that the process of JITing can be faster than fork+exec of a C compiler.  (And you can make functions that take an address or two as a pointer arg, or even take double args by value, instead of having to hard-code absolute addresses into the machine code, although you could do that with C.)  And if you JIT, you can choose branchless if you're manually doing the code-gen.  But only if you have your own JIT engine or template; if you leave it to LLVM or something, then it's up to the optimizer back-end.

Comment: Ah okay. The initial time is actually not an issue. It's okay if it takes 10-20 seconds (1min would be a bit long). I've just googled branchless for XGBoost and found this: https://cds.cern.ch/record/2688585/files/AA_main.pdf Cool idea with JIT+branchless. I'll try that:)!

Comment: @KevinMeier Re "a tree data structure was way too slow": There is more than one way to encode and traverse trees though (but without more information it is hard to say whether you can optimize that approach)